# Look up a field that contains a specific letter and return the description/name

Tags: field, lookup

I have a six digit code that contains a letter and i want a formula that will look to see if the code contains a certain letter and return the descirption for that code

for example the code field will be 6201-L
L equals Electrical so I want the formula to return "Electrical"

The next code may be 6201-J
J equals Job so I want the formula to return the text "Job"

the letters will always be constant but the numbers can change
i.e. sometime the number will be 6203-J so I also need to use a space holder in the formula so it is only searching for the letter

can anyone help please? 
Thanks

Comment: Will it always come after a dash?

Comment: Yes it will always come after a dash